# "I wondered if you were free this evening." - Does it sound like a normal polite question?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

Below are sentences taken from the Oxford English Grammar Course (Oxford University Press 2015). The title of the section is "Requests, questions and suggestions".

1. I wonder if you need any help./I wondered if you needed any help.[= Do you need any help now?]
2. I wonder if you are free this evening./I wondered if you were free this evening.[=Are you free this evening?]
3. We wonder if you have two single rooms./We wondered if you had two single rooms.[=Do you have two single rooms now?]

The sentences I quoted are all questions about what’s taking place now, not about how things were at some previous time (this is what the book says).
The tense change (from Present to Past) is supposed to make the sentences sound more polite.
A similar example is “Did you want to pay, sir?” It’s the same as “Do you want to pay now, sir?”, where the Past Simple tense makes it sound more polite. But it’s about what’s happening right now, at the present moment. The same applies to the three sentences I listed above.
It seems obvious that these are polite questions, but they sound rather strange to me (though I'm not a native speaker of English). It's the first time I've seen the verb "wonder" used in such a way. The sentences are from a grammar book by Oxford University Press (published 8 years ago), which must be a reliable source of information, right?

I wonder if they do sound natural and to what extent they are idiomatic.

Thank you.

Comment: Let's separate the timeframes: "Did you want to pay, sir?" asks if you wanted (in the past) to pay (at present). "I wondered if you were free this evening" says I thought (in the past) about whether you are free (at present) for a date? So subtle, it's not an outright question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already referring to a book from a respected publisher in linguistics, I suppose you can only be asking for native-speaker intuition. So here's mine (40-year native speaker).

I think in general one can make a statement less direct (and thus less "aggressive", or interfering) by distancing it in terms of tense, time, modality, etc. So "I want" is more direct than "I would like"; and "I wonder" is rather gentle, but still more direct than "I wondered" or "I was wondering" (where, if you reject my request, I can pretend that it was only in the past anyway, and no longer relevant).

An example of the same thing in the other direction: charities asking for money will ask very directly "WILL YOU GIVE JUST TEN POUNDS?", because saying no to this question is a direct cancellation, whereas "would you consider..." can be batted aside easily.

Again: this is just native-speaking intuition because your question began by quoting an academic source.

Answer (score 1):

If I say “I wonder if you are free”, it says that I am presently in a state of not knowing if or not you are free. My invitation to you is to reply now and change my state to knowing which is true.

If I say “I wondered if you were free” it says that at some previous time I was in the state of not knowing. It also implies that I am not presently in that state. Therefore the matter is not as urgent to me as when I use the present tense.

The past might even be interpreted literally as a simple statement of how things *were*, that they no longer *are*. This gives the listener opportunity to avoid the invitation with “*Oh yes I would have been free, but …*”

In this way the use of the past tense to refer to a present request reduces the emotional pressure on the listener and is therefore more polite.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
The sentences I quoted are all polite questions about what’s taking place now, not about how things were at some previous time (this is what the book says).
1. I wonder if you need any help./I wondered if you needed any help. [= Do you need any help now?]
2. I wonder if you are free this evening./I wondered if you were free this evening. [=Are you free this evening?]
3. We wonder if you have two single rooms./We wondered if you had two single rooms. [=Do you have two single rooms now?]

Comment: A similar example is “Did you want to pay, sir?” It’s the same as “Do you want to pay now, sir?”, where the Past Simple tense makes it sound more polite. But it’s about what’s happening right now, at the present moment. The same applies to the three sentences I listed above. 
I wonder if they do sound natural and to what extent they are idiomatic.